# Авторизация реализована на основе ролей (Roles) в C#. Вложенные роли Configure и Configure.Set

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, авторизация

Погружаюсь в новый проект, где используется ролевая модель в C#. Авторизация реализована на основе ролей в ASP.NET Core. Имеются роли, часть названий которых содержит другие роли (некая вложенность). К примеру, есть роль `Configure` и роль `Configure.Set`. Интересует вопрос в C# и ASP.NET Core подразумевается, что `Configure` включает в себя `Configure.Set` или наоборот `Configure.Set` включает `Configure`? Или же никакого отношения друг к другу эти роли иметь не будут и будут считаться независимыми?

Comment: Почему бы об этом не спросить свою команду?